# PYTHON: Multiple conditions in list comprehensions - matching strings

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I have:

```
mylist = ['person1 has apples', 'oranges and apples', 'person2 has oranges']

matchers = ['person1','person2']
```

My desire output is a list of strings that contain strings in matchers:

```
output = ['person1 has apples', 'person2 has oranges']
```

I have managed to achieve this writing out each item from matching list explicitly, but the actual data is much bigger than this example so I am looking for better way to achieve the output.

This works:

```
matching = [s for s in mylist if "person1" in s or "person2" in s]
```

But it requires listing every item from matchers explicitly.

I have tried this:

```
matching = [s for s in mylist if any(x in s for x in matchers)]
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float
```

However, it only produces an error message when there are no matches in the list of strings. When there is a match from matchers in mylist - the code works. Not sure why!

** EDIT - typo corrected. There was no typo in the code that produced the error **

** EDIT2 - code is correct, there was a NaN in the list of matchers! **

Comment: @AKX's answer reveals that the problem was just a typo; typing `x` instead of `xs` results in the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo; you've probably assigned a float to `x` earlier, and

```
matching = [s for s in mylist if any(x in s for xs in matchers)]
```

refers to it.

Maybe be more explicit with names:

```
matching = [text for text in mylist if any((matcher in text) for matcher in matchers)]
```

## An example

```
mylist = [
    "person1 has apples",
    "oranges and apples",
    "person2 has oranges",
]
matchers = ["person1", "person2"]
matching = [
    text
    for text in mylist
    if any(matcher in text for matcher in matchers)
]
print(mylist)
print(matchers)
print(matching)
```

outputs

```
['person1 has apples', 'oranges and apples', 'person2 has oranges']
['person1', 'person2']
['person1 has apples', 'person2 has oranges']
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have now corrected the typo - it was only in the post not in my original code! I have now also added to the post that the code works when there are matches, but it throws an error when there are no matches.

Comment: @Aleksnadra I added an example. It works fine with an empty `mylist` and an empty `matchers`. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have found an issue, there was a "nan" in my long list of matchers.. Thanks for your help, the code works fine!

Comment: Glad you found the issue!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
`matching = [s for s in mylist if any(m in s for m in matchers)]`

Comment: thanks for your comment. That's exactly what I have tried but it only works when there are matches. It throws an error when there are no matches.